Find position vector in spherical coordinates given Fx, Fy, Fz, Mx, My, Mz, and r
I've run into a bit of a roadblock figuring out this problem. I need to find the position vector given all three dimensions of force and moment as well as the radius of the sphere.
I've gotten the angle between the force vector and the position vector by rearranging the equation:
$$
M = |r||F|sin(α)u
$$
to the form:
$$
α = arcsin(|M|*(|r||F|)^{-1})
$$
but I am struggling to figure out how to accurately project the position vector onto the Theta and Phi planes of the spherical coordinate system. My guess is that it's going to be a function of the Phi projection of the moment since the plane that the position and force vectors are on will always be orthogonal to the moment vector.
Thank you in advance for any help!

What sphere? Please explain the details of your question as we do not see what you see.

Not clear what you are asking.
In cartesian coordinates, you know a force acts though a line in space called the line of action. If you measure the resulting moment at the origin that is given by $$\vec{M} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$$ then you can find the point on the line closest to the origin using
$$ \vec{r}_{0} = \frac{ \vec{F} \times \vec{M} } { \| \vec{F} \|^2 } $$
where any point on the line is described by the ray
$$ \vec{r} = \vec{r}_0 + \lambda\, \hat{e} $$
where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary distance value, and $\hat{e} = \vec{F} / \| \vec{F} \|$ is the direction of the line.
At is point you can take the components of $\vec{r}_0$ and do the cartesian to spherical coordinate transformation according to your specification for spherical coordinates.
